# elementary OS installer crashed at choosing partition screen

Tags: system-installation, release-juno

I'm new to Linux and this is the first time i tried to [dual-boot](/questions/tagged/dual-boot) Linux. My laptop is Dell XPS 9360.
When ever i use the [usb](/questions/tagged/usb) to boot elementary OS(i tried Ubuntu too and get the same error message), i get to boot but when i run the installer and at the choose partition page there is nothing to choose. And when i press the <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>change</kbd> button it opens a window telling me installer crashed
this is the error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-partman.py", line 1302, in on_partition_list_edit_activate
    self.partman_dialog(devpart, partition, create=False)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/plugin.py", line 48, in wrapper
    return target(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-partman.py", line 983, in partman_dialog
    if ('can_resize' not in partition or not partition['can_resize'] or
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I am using UEFI boot option and I've tried both with secure boot on/off and fastboot on/off. When i tried legacy boot it doesn't even [boot](/questions/tagged/boot) and shows an error message saying,

```
kernal panic and initramfs unpacking failed junk in compressed archive
```

Comment: Hi Edwin, welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. I have made some changes on your post to make it look better though your choice of words DO describe your problem well.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a new Laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad 330S) and was having exactly the same problem as you. After many frustrating hours of research, I discovered that it's a compatibility issue between Linux and the laptop's default storage controller.

Basically from what I understand, Linux needs it to be in AHCI mode in order to properly access the partitions, and by default the laptop was configured for RAID (using Intel Rapid Storage).

You can change it to AHCI easily by accessing the BIOS, but since Windows 10 was installed with RAID enabled, doing so would make it unbootable. There are a few ways you can try to change it without breaking the windows installation ([check this blogpost](https://hetmanrecovery.com/recovery_news/how-to-enable-ahci-mode-for-sata-in-the-bios-without-reinstalling-windows.htm)) but since it was a new laptop, I made a bootable Windows usb stick from the official ISO, formatted the drive and made a clean install after changing the storage controller settings to AHCI. Afterwards I was able to install ElementaryOS Juno without any problems.

You can read more about the dual boot problem with RAID [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867488/dell-xps-13-9360-dualboot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04#) (check the most upvoted answer for a step by step description).

**TL;DR**

1. Get a bootable Windows USB stick and back up any data you may want to keep
2. Check BIOS for Storage Controller
3. Change it to AHCI
4. Boot from the Windows USB stick
5. Format drive with current windows installation and do a clean install
6. Try again to run the ElementaryOS installer

Comment: I´m having the same isue here, but with a small difference. When trying to install bodhi linux in my laptop the same message appears. The thing is I´m not booting from a cd or a flash drive. I´m using Unetbootin which boots from an ISO placed in my windows desktop. Do you think that if I enter the BIOS and change those settings the windows could crash and I will also be unable to open the linux installer? Thanks for any help